# display list of pages of content type using views + edit and delete option

Tags: views, theming, nodes

I've installed the [Views Bulk Operations](https://drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) module (VBO). Using this I want to create a block/page to  load all the pages of particular content-type. But it should include options like update + check boxes, edit/delete. See the screenshot below. 
[image]

I couldn't find the built in view 'content', so I've to create from scratch. Please give me solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution by installing [Admin VBO Views](https://drupal.org/project/admin_vbo_views) module

Comment: But, I couldn't find check box option to select individual or all option to delete/edit

Answer (score -1):

Check `admin/structure/views/view/admin_views_node`

Comment: Can you explain what the user should do on this page?